# Guassian elimination with partial pivoting matlab code

Tags: matlab

I am having a really hard time trying to understand how pivoting has been implemented in this code. Can somebody please explain how partial pivoting has been implemented here?

```
 % PARTIAL PIVOTING
    for k = 1:n
    i = k;
    for j = i+1:n
        if(M(j, i) > M(i, j))
        i = j;
        end
    end
    if(k ~= i)
    M([k i], :) = M([i k], :);
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the full code I believe.

It is basically finding the row with the largest value (though it should use absolute value in the comparison) below the current row. I am not sure which part you don't understand but I believe it may be the line:

```
M([k i], :) = M([i k], :);
```

That line is simply swapping the row k and i. It is same as doing;

```
temp=M(i,:)
M(i,:)=M(k,:);
M(k,:)=temp;
```

After this line you then need to do the row reduction.

See below for a full gaussian elimination code in matlab (only reduced to upper triangular form);

```
function a = gauss_pivot(a)
[m,~] =size(a);
for i=1:m-1
    %find pivot position 
    pivot_pos = find(max(abs(a(i:end,i)))==abs(a(i:end,i)),1)+i-1;  % the 1 in find is 
                                                               %to return a single row
    %swap row
    if(pivot_pos ~= i)
        a([i, pivot_pos],:)=a([pivot_pos,i],:);
    end
    %reduce row
    a(i+1:end,i:end)=a(i+1:end,i:end)-a(i,i:end).*a(i+1:end,i)/a(i,i);
end
end
```